# Automation on Opening CSV file in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have often to open CSV files in Excel (14.0.6112.5000; Office 2010). The data is filled well in the columns, but the DateTime values exceed the default column with and are display as ######. So I have to manually change this width. Further I would like to have to freeze the window at row/colum C2.

Is there a way to do this when opening a CSV automatically or have a script that can be activated by a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this by recording a macro.  So choose the `Developer` tab, and `Record Macro`.

Then do the sequence <kbd>Ctrl-A</kbd><kbd>Alt-H</kbd><kbd>o</kbd><kbd>i</kbd>

This selects all, goes to the Home tab, format, and autofit columns

And stop recording the macro.  You can then save the macro, and give it a shortcut key to activate it when you want.

You could also carry out the freeze panes for the top row this way also.

Comment: Since it is just 3 key combinations you might as well save yourself the macro and just do `[Alt+h] [o] [i]` every time you open a CSV file

Comment: Unless there is a way to run a macro automatically on every CSV file that is opened?